# Confidence Interval with tbl_regression

Tags: gtsummary

I've used the glm function to perform an univariate regression:

```
data_glm<-data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),c("ctl","ctl","ctl","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","ctl","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt","trt"))
colnames(data_glm) <- c("response", "arm")

glm.fit <- glm(response ~ arm, data = data_glm, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(glm.fit)
```

R Output

```
Call:
glm(formula = response ~ arm, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = data_glm)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -1.3863     0.6455  -2.148 0.031742 *  
arm trt   2.6391     0.7384   3.574 0.000352 ***
```

I would like to use tbl_regression to summarize these results. Unfortunately the resulting CI are not the Wald CI, for example for ARM: trt 14.0 (3.65 to 71.0) with the following code:

```
 tbl_regression(glm.fit, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Is there an option to get the Wald CI?

Thanks,
LM

Comment: can you share you data and code so we can help

Answer (score 1):

If you want the wald CI you can use the example on the gtsummary help page to walk you through this. Extra help here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#wald-ci.

here is the code on how to get wald ci.

```
my_tidy <- function(x, exponentiate =  FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...) {
  dplyr::bind_cols(
    broom::tidy(x, exponentiate = exponentiate, conf.int = FALSE),
    # calculate the confidence intervals, and save them in a tibble
    stats::confint.default(x) %>%
      tibble::as_tibble() %>%
      rlang::set_names(c("conf.low", "conf.high"))  )
}

lm(age ~ grade + marker, trial) %>%
  tbl_regression(tidy_fun = my_tidy)
```